# Finding an equivalence relation for a sequence defined by integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, equivalence-relations

A [recent topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742273/study-convergence-of-series-sum-x-n-with-x-n1-int-0x-n-cosnt) on MSE involved dealing with the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $0 < x_0 < \pi$ and $$x_{n+1}=\int_0^{x_n} \cos^n(t) \, dt$$ for all integers $n \geq 0$. I am wondering how to find an equivalence of $x_n$ when $n \to +\infty.$

Many thanks.